# PowerShell - Default Action if no Parameter is Specified

Tags: powershell, parameters

Been struggling to find a way to word this, which is probably why I'm also having trouble finding out how to do it, so apologies if this is a simple thing to achieve or has been asked before.

I'm creating a basic TUI in PowerShell as a learning exercise.  I've created a function that draws a window header which you can pass parameters to in order to determine the width, content etc:

```
Draw-Line -ConsoleWidth 80 -Position top -LeftContent "Window Title" -RightContent "I'm on the right"
```

Returns:

```
┌──┤ Window Title ├───────────────────────────────────────┤ I'm on the right ├──
```

The length of the line between the left and right text is calculated by taking the length of the text in both `$leftContent` and `$RightContent` variables, then subtracting those values from the `$ConsoleWidth` variable.

What I'm having trouble with now is making it so that if I don't pass, for example, a `-RightContent` parameter, it prints something else (in my case a bunch of ─ to continue the line).  I'm assuming this could be achieved with a conditional statement, something like `if $var is not set, $var2 = 'foo'`, but nothing I'm trying is working.

My function:

```
function Draw-Line{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $ConsoleWidth,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $Position,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $LeftContent,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $RightContent
    )

    $Bar = "─"

    if ( $Position -eq "top" ){
        $BeforeLeft = "┌──┤ "
    } elseif ( $Position -eq "bottom" ){
        $BeforeLeft = "└──┤ "
    } else {
        $BeforeLeft = "───┤ "
    }

    $AfterLeft = " ├"
    $LeftTotal = $BeforeLeft + $AfterLeft + $LeftContent
    $BeforeRight = "┤ "
    $AfterRight = " ├──"
    $RightTotal = $BeforeRight + $RightContent + $AfterRight 
    $Difference = $ConsoleWidth - ( $LeftTotal.Length + $RightTotal.Length )
    $Line = $Bar * $Difference

    Write-Host "<........|.........|.........|.........|.........|.........|.........|.........>" #Debug line for confirming widths, 80 columns wide.

#Draw the line:    
    Write-Host $BeforeLeft -ForegroundColor $LineColor -NoNewline
    Write-Host $LeftContent -ForegroundColor $TitleColor -NoNewline
    Write-Host $AfterLeft -ForegroundColor $LineColor -NoNewline 
    Write-Host $Line -ForegroundColor $LineColor -NoNewline
    Write-Host $BeforeRight -ForegroundColor $LineColor -NoNewline
    Write-Host $RightContent -ForegroundColor $LineColor -NoNewline 
    Write-Host $AfterRight -ForegroundColor $LineColor
}
```

I've half-managed to achieve what I needed, by writing conditional statements that set the values of some variables if "none" is passed as a value to the parameter.

```
if ( $LeftContent -eq "none" ){
    $LeftContent,$BeforeLeft,$AfterLeft = ""
} else {
    $BeforeLeft = "┤ "
    $AfterLeft = " ├"
}
```

This works, but ideally I'd like to specify somewhere that if the parameter isn't used, then "none" is assumed as the default.  I've looked up parameter default values ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.1)), but this seems to suggest setting something globally, whereas I'm hoping that I'd be able to set some sort of default value to each parameter, something like:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Default = "none")] [string] $LeftContent
```

I'm pretty new to scripting, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable to evaluate against a missing, or present key (*parameters* - *to include values* ). You're on the right track already: `if (-not$PSBoundParamters.ContainsKey('RightContent')) { <# My Code Here#> }`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if formatting is janky, using mobile; If you want to add default values then you can set it in your parameter variable.

```
function Draw-Line{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
 [string] $ConsoleWidth,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] 
[string] $Position,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] 
[string] $LeftContent = “default value”,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] 
[string] $RightContent = “default value”
    )
```

This way if they don’t specify a left or right content, it’ll automatically use what you have set as a default